# How to programmatically select ClientRegistration

Tags: java, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement a module for a larger application that can access user data with OIDC. The challenge here is that the application acts as a relay for a multitude of clients that may access their own OIDC-server, so autoconfiguring via application.properties is not a viable option.
Likewise, registering all `ClientRegistration`s in the `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository` is not a viable option, as users for client A may not use the `ClientRegistration` for client B and vice-versa.

The paragraph above this already showy a large part of my knowledge in this matter:

- it is simple to register up to `n` `ClientRegistration` objects
- all registered `ClientRegistration` objects **can** be autodetected by Spring and will be selectable on the login page

I have already "implemented" a `ClientRegistrationRepository` like so:

```java
@Service
public class MyCustomRepository implements ClientRegistrationRepository {
  private final Map<String, ClientRegistration> registrations = new HashMap<>();

  public MyCustomRepository() {
    addDefaultRegistrations();
  }

  @Override
  public ClientRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
    return registrations.get(registrationId);
  }

  private void addDefaultRegistrations() {
   // omitted
  }    
}
```

It is deliberate that this does not implement `Iterable<ClientRegistration>` for reasons already stated.
When using this and no custom login page, the default login page is empty.

When allowing autodetection of `ClientRegistration`s via `Iterable`, and given that only a single `ClientRegistration` is registered, the login page is not being displayed, instead the authorization endpoint `<server>/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}` is used directly.

What I am trying to do is replicating this behavior with a custom login "page".
The page is supposed to automatically "decide" which ClientRegistration should be used to initiate the authentication flow.

I have tried to add a custom login page url with a wildcard and a path variable; both are not being interpolated, which leads to invalid login requests. That does make sense, but I tried it nonetheless.
Now I have a Controller method which accepts the `SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST`-attribute, reads the original url and extracts the clientId from there, and then sends a redirect to the corresponding endpoint:

```java
    @GetMapping("/doLogin")
    public String login(
            @SessionAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST") SavedRequest originalRequest,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String originalUrl = originalRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        String[] parts = originalUrl.split("/");
        String id = parts[parts.length - 1];
        return "redirect:/login/oauth2/code/" + id;
    }
```

This, however, interrupts processing due to "too many requests".

**Edit 1**
I just found that the "too many redirects" happen because an OAuth2AuthenticationException with the message "[invalid_request]" is thrown somewhere. Sadly it does not appear in my stack anywhere and keycloak does not register it, so i cannot find any more details atm.
**Edit 1 end**
If I understand the default login page correctly, it TECHNICALLY does nothing else, except a new request is fired instead of a "simple" redirect.

As each client can only access a single `ClientRegistration` object, the selection SHOULD be possible without user interaction.

From what I gathered from the docs, the approach is strictly speaking not entirely wrong, but definitely not correct.

So the question/s are as follows:

- Can I code a login page that will automatically select the "correct" url to start the flow?
- How can I modify my approach so that it might do what it should?

Note: while being extremely hacky, using a thymeleaf template with an instant redirect is possible, but I would try to avoid this. Likewise, building the authentication start URL outside of this module is possible, but also most likely not a viable option - unless I missed something.

Final note: when using a single ClientRegistration object, the entire communication works out of the box, 
so the problem does not appear to be on the server. I am using KeyCloak 9.0.0 as OpenId provider.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I found the solution and my mistake.
The approach does work, perfectly even, however the correct URLs must be used.
The custom login page must - in my case, at least, not redirect directly to the filter URL, but rather to

`/oauth2/authorize/{clientId}`

this starts the process and completes as expected.